# LocalStack Invoking Lambda Functions keeps resulting in AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, docker-compose, localstack

I am trying to invoke a terraformed lambda function under the localstack environment however it keeps returning an assume role 200 in the docker container I am running it on.

My docker container logs

```
2023-07-19 10:42:35 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:35.522  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:36 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:36.526  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:37 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:37.523  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:38 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:38.523  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:39 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:39.524  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:40 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:40.524  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:41 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:41.525  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:42 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:42.525  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:43 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:43.525  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:44 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:44.526  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:45 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:45.527  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:46 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:46.527  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:47 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:47.528  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:48 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:48.528  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:49 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:49.529  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:50 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:50.530  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:51 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:51.530  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:52 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:52.530  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
2023-07-19 10:42:53 localstack_main  | 2023-07-19T02:42:53.531  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_4] localstack.request.aws     : AWS sts.AssumeRole => 200
```

My lambda function I am trying to invoke

```
SUCCESS = {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'Request Succeeded.'}

def lambda_handler(event, context):          

    print(str(event))
    
    return SUCCESS
```

Command I use to invoke my lambda function
`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name test-dev-test-app --payload '{}' response.json`

Command I use to start up my docker compose file
`docker compose up`

My Docker Compose File

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = ap-southeast-1
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3,cloudformation,sts,apigateway,iam,route53,dynamodb
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I was hoping to see a response message of `{'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'Request Succeeded.'}` from the lambda function after invoking it however it results in a continuous assume role 200 in my docker container. Eventually I also receive a timeout message

`Read timeout on endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/2015-03-31/functions/test-dev-test-app/invocations"`

Comment: I don't have any solution (I'm facing the same problem myself), but is there a chance you have [hot reloading](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/lambda-tools/hot-reloading/) turned on for your lambda?

Comment: No I don't believe I turned on hot reloading for my lambda. I terraform my lambda function while pointing my endpoint to localstack but when I try to invoke my function I keep getting sts assume role 200